# MongoDB extract specific value python

Tags: python, mongodb, bash

I want to extract value of name :

```
x = col.find({},{'_id': 0, 'country.name': 1})
 
for data in x:
    #if data == 'India':
        print(data['country'])
```

This above code generate this output:

```
{'name': 'India'}
{'name': 'Colombia'}
{'name': 'Iran (Islamic Republic of)'}
{'name': 'Germany'}
```

Desire output:
India
Colombia
Iran (Islamic Republic of)
Germany

In mongodb every entris have id but name of country is subarray of array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We need to create a `list` and append country name in that, and use `join` outside the for loop, It will print the expected output.

```
countries = []
for data in x:
    countries.append(data.get("country", {}).get("name"))
print("Output: ", " ".join(countries))
```